# Roles based authorization breaking my app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

The registration works fine, user is created, and the role the new user chooses is applied fine.  On some controllers I restrict access with [Authorize] and this works good with the user being redirected to the login.  The problem arises when I want to authorize by roles.  When I change

[Authorize]

to

[Authorize(Roles = "Sales")]
 the app hangs before the browser reports the error:

---

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:

The connection string specifies a local Sql Server Express instance using a database location within the application's App_Data directory. The provider attempted to automatically create the application services database because the provider determined that the database does not exist. The following configuration requirements are necessary to successfully check for existence of the application services database and automatically create the application services database:

---

This only happens when I add the role condition.  The Default connection in the Web.Config points to the SQL Server database I am using.  For some reason, the condition of allowing only certain roles makes it want to start creating a database with SQLExpress

Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Comment: Remove any references to WebMatrix, if your project has them.

Comment: I don't think there are any references, not that I can find anyway.

Comment: Did you create the role beforehand?